# Installing Ubuntu destroyed everything

Tags: windows

I'll try to be short and simple.

- I had Windows 8.1 (came with the computer)
- I tried to install Ubuntu
- I accidentally clicked continue with "erase disk and install" selected.
- Now everything is gone... My laptop doesn't even seem to have a factory image to reset to.
- No, I did not backup anything. :(

Ubuntu seems to be installed on my computer, and there is only one drive anymore (the now dedicated Ubuntu drive, I guess...).

Is there anyway I can undelete my hard disk? I just want my Windows 8 back...

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible. Do you want Windows 8 back primarily? Or do you want your *data* back? (I.E., documents)

Comment: For **data** see http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu **Windows 8** needs to be re-installed, as to near certainty it was partly overwritten and can't be recovered.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely to restore the original contents of the hard drive. During install Ubuntu creates new partitions and formats the drive. That's why there's only one partition left (actually there are more like the swap partition, but you can't see those). These operations however destroyed the original data. Your only chance is a Windows recovery disk or partition or go to a recovery expert which is usually very expensive so that's only a last resort in case your data is valuable and irreplacable.

Comment: Thank you,  Wie5Ooma.  And yes, I was after my data.